# pygame "Paint" program - drawing empty rectangle on canvas

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm making an MS-Paint-like program using pygame (to which I'm completely new), which has been going well so far, except for this annoying problem that I have.
I want the user to have the ability to draw a rectangle by dragging the mouse along the canvas, similar to how you do in MS-Paint, and I want it to look as if the rectangle is "moving" as long as the mouse is being dragged.
I managed to have it work perfectly yet inefficiently until I was advised that I should use some other pygame methods to make it more efficient. So I did, and the one problem I can't solve is that previous images of the rectangle remain on the screen. Like so:
[Top-left is where I started to draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcZD4.png)
Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
        if canvas.collidepoint(cursor) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and mode == 'Square' and not draw_square:
            start_x, start_y = find_pixel(mouse_x, mouse_y)
            width, height = find_pixel(mouse_x, mouse_y)
            save_last = screen.subsurface(start_x, start_y, width - start_x, height - start_y)
            square = pygame.draw.rect(screen, current_color, (start_x, start_y, width - start_x, height - start_y), 5)
            temp_square = square
            draw_square = True

        if draw_square and canvas.collidepoint(cursor) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            # Mouse is being held down outside canvas, show square progress
            prev_width, prev_height = width, height
            save_last = screen.subsurface(temp_square)
            width, height = find_pixel(mouse_x, mouse_y)
            if width != prev_width or height != prev_height:
                square = temp_square.inflate(width - start_x, height - start_y)
                square.topleft = start_x, start_y
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, current_color, square, 5)

        if not canvas.collidepoint(cursor) and draw_square:
            # Mouse is being held down outside canvas, show square progress
            width, height = find_pixel(mouse_x, mouse_y)
            if width < 150:  # Cursor is left of the canvas
                width = 150
            if width > 980:  # Cursor is right of the canvas
                width = 980
            if height < 20:  # Cursor is above the canvas
                height = 20
            if height > 580:  # Cursor if below the canvas
                height = 580

            square = temp_square.inflate(width - start_x, height - start_y)
            square.topleft = start_x, start_y
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, current_color, square, 5)

        if draw_square and not pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            draw_square = False

        pygame.display.flip()
```

I've tried blitting `save_last` onto the screen but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yargr/PycharmProjects/Paint/PaintApp.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/yargr/PycharmProjects/Paint/PaintApp.py", line 435, in main
    screen.blit(save_last, (mouse_x, mouse_y))
pygame.error: Surfaces must not be locked during blit
```

I've tried using `screen.unlock()` but it didn't work (I guess I don't completely understand how that works). Anyway, if anyone has any idea, I;d love to hear suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `save_last` is a subsurface of screen, because of

> ```py
> save_last = screen.subsurface(start_x, start_y, width - start_x, height - start_y)
> ```

respectively

> ```py
> save_last = screen.subsurface(temp_square)
> ```

`subsurface()` creates a surface which references to the other surface. The new Surface shares its pixels with the other parent. The new surface has no own data.

If you do

> ```py
> screen.blit(save_last, (mouse_x, mouse_y))
> ```

then it seems that the `screen` gets temporary looked, when `save_last` is read, because it is referenced. Finally writing to `screen` fails.

But you can solve the issue by directly copying a region of `screen` to `screen` by [`.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). Do not create a subsurface, just notice the rectangular region ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) and copy the region form the `screen` [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to another position on `screen`. e.g:

```py
save_rect = pygame.Rect(start_x, start_y, width - start_x, height - start_y)

# [...]

save_rect = pygame.Rect(temp_square)

# [...]

screen.blit(screen, (mouse_x, mouse_y), area=save_rect)
```

Alternatively you can crate a copy of the rectangular region and `blit` the copy to `screen`:

```py
save_rect = pygame.Rect(start_x, start_y, width - start_x, height - start_y)
save_last = pygame.Surface(save_rect.size)
save_last.blit(screen, (0, 0), save_rect)

# [...]

save_rect = pygame.Rect(temp_square)
save_last = pygame.Surface(save_rect.size)
save_last.blit(screen, (0, 0), save_rect)

# [...]

screen.blit(save_last, (mouse_x, mouse_y))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It did seem to solve the locking problem, however when trying to create the copy of the rectangular portion of the screen with `save_last = pygame.Surface(save_rect.size)`, I'm getting this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yargr/PycharmProjects/Paint/PaintApp.py", line 564, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/yargr/PycharmProjects/Paint/PaintApp.py", line 423, in main
    save_last = pygame.Surface(save_rect.size)
pygame.error: Invalid resolution for Surface`

Comment: @YaronGrushka Probably the width or height of the surface is less or equal 0. It is impossible for me to find the reason for that error. You've to debug your application. Do `print(save_rect.size)` before `pygame.Surface(save_rect.size)` to investigate the size of the rectangle.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that that it's because I am setting the size of the rect as `width - start_x, height - start_y` and since `width` is equal `start_x` and `height` is equal `start_y`, I'm getting a surface with an invalid size. I'll try getting around it somehow.